# Spring JMS standalone module initialization

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I've look to simple sample for create standalone module that used spring for handling JMS.

I try to google some example but i only found cuts of configuration and java code - not full sample of application. So my main issue that i don't understand requirements for init and run standalone JMS  module with Spring.

I have one requirement - output type of artifact should EAR (restriction).

For example, i found the code for consumer and configuration in doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html, part 21.4.2 Asynchronous Reception - Message-Driven POJOs, but i don't understand how to wrap this code to run it under any EE container.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for; producer? consumer? You also say standalone, but then it must be an EAR. You need to make your question much clearer and provide more details.

Comment: It's not improtant. I just search of example for any standalone application (that running in some server - weblogic,glassfish etc) which use JMS with Spring.

Comment: Usually you need only to create JMS queues in your favorite EE server, and when you need it in spring, lookup it from jndi and use.

Comment: Excalty. But i don't have 'main' like in simple jar. Where i need to init jms context (new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) for EE container?

Comment: You can create EJB with `@Startup` and `@Singleton` annotations, in that class create methods for start and stop spring context, and mark that methods with `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotation. Easiest way, i think, if you're using EE container.

Comment: Sound good, let try it.

Answer (score 0):

An EAR application is not standalone, but requires a Java EE application server to run.

[This official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbpk/index.html) shows a basic JMS sample as an EAR application.

You need to download and setup the Glassfish application server, Netbeans IDE and tutorial source code, instructions are found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gfiud/index.html).

Comment: Yes, but it is EJB example with MDB. I found same example for Spring.

Comment: So you have a spring only requirement?

Comment: Yes, i need spring to use features like wire-tap and interceptor.